# What can be said about an ideal whose vanishing locus consists of a single point?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

From classical algebraic geometry we learn that maximal ideals in polynomial rings correspond to points, in the sense that if $K$ is an algebraically closed field, and $\mathfrak a$ is a maximal ideal in $K[x_1,\dots,x_n]$, then there is a $p\in\mathbb A^n$ such that $\mathfrak a=I(\{p\})$, and hence $V(\mathfrak a)=\{p\}$. On the other hand, if $\mathfrak a$ is an ideal, and $V(\mathfrak a)=\{p\}$, then it does *not* follow that $\mathfrak a$ is a maximal ideal.

My question is: if we know that $\mathfrak a$ is an ideal such that $V(\mathfrak a)=\{p\}$, what *can* we conclude about $\mathfrak a$? It of course follows from the Nullstellensatz that $I(V(\mathfrak a))=\sqrt{\mathfrak a}=I(\{p\})$, but I wonder if there is more that can be said.

Comment: Do you want something more than "for each $i$ there exists $m_i\geq 1$ such that $(x_i-p_i)^{m_i}\in\mathfrak{a}$, where $p=(p_1,\ldots,p_n)$"?

Comment: Ideally, yes. I think one possible answer would be a way of marking out the maximal ideals as "special" amongst the ideals which have a vanish locus consisting of a single point. Of course, we can already say that the maximal ideals are special in the sense that they are the radical ideals which have a zero locus consisting of a single point, but I was hoping for a little more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Claim:.** $V(\mathfrak{a}) = \{\mathbf{p}=(p_1,\ldots,p_n)\}$ if and only if $\mathfrak{a}\neq (1)$ and for each $i$, $1\leq i\leq n$ there exists $m_i\geq 1$ such that $(x_i-p_i)^{m_i}\in\mathfrak{a}$.

I think this is the best you can say: the maximal ideals are precisely the ideals of the form $(x_1-a_1,\ldots,x_n-a_n)$ for some $(a_1,\ldots,a_n)\in k^n$: that such ideals are maximal is clear, since $k[x_1,\ldots,x_n]/(x_1-a_1,\ldots,x_n-a_n)\cong k$ via evaluation. That any maximal ideal is of that form follows because if $I$ is maximal, then $k[x_1,\ldots,x_n]/I$ is a finite extension of $k$, and therefore isomorphic to $k$, since $k$ is algebraically closed. Fix an isomorphism $k[x_1,\ldots,x_n]/I\cong k$, which we may assume restricts to the identity on $k$, and let $r_i$ be the image of $x_i$ in $k$. Then $(x_1-r_1,\ldots,x_n-r_n)\subseteq I$, so maximality gives $I=(x_1-r_1,\ldots,x_n-r_n)$.

So if $V(\mathfrak{a})$ consists of a single point, then $\sqrt{\mathfrak{a}} = (x_1-a_1,\ldots,x_n-a_n)$ for some $(a_1,\ldots,a_n)\in k^n$, which just translates to the statement given.

Alternatively, you can argue as follows: if $\mathfrak{a}$ satisfies that condition, and $\mathbf{q}=(q_1,\ldots,q_n)\in V(\mathfrak{a})$, then $q_i-p_i=0$ for each $i$, so $q_i=p_i$; so $V(\mathfrak{a})\subseteq \{\mathbf{p}\}$. And since $\mathfrak{a}\neq(1)$, then $V(\mathfrak{a})\neq\varnothing$, so $V(\mathfrak{a})=\{\mathbf{p}\}$.

Conversely, assume that $V(\mathfrak{a})=\{\mathbf{p}\}$. Then $\mathfrak{a}\neq (1)$, and for each $i$, $x_i-p_i\in I(V(\mathfrak{a}))=\sqrt{\mathfrak{a}}$, hence there exists $m_i$ such that $(x_i-p_i)^{m_i}\in \mathfrak{a}$. $\Box$